# How to define named query in Spring data Neo4j 4

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

How can I define a named query in Spring data Neo4J 4.0.0? In earlier release 3.4.1 [`@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/Query.html) annotation had `queryName` attribute. Now it is not available

Edit: As mentioned in the answer, named-queries are currently not supported. Created a new [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-791) for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named queries are not supported in SDN 4.

Please open a feature request at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/ if it's a must-have for you